# Multilenguage data in web application

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I am developing a web application about restaurant management, and I want to store different categories and can access them in the language of my choice.
I am using mySQL and my application is developed in Java+Spring+Hibernate+Tapestry.
How can I do this?  Storing names in database in three or four languages?

Comment: Use ResourceBundle class and *.properties files: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev read my comment below please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'll countinue my answer here and describe some details, that was not covered in my comments.

Create *.properties file for each language you plan to use. Their contents for example:

I18n_en.properties

> category.dinners=Dinners

I18n_es.properties

> category.dinners=Bebidas

User on the site clicks button or link, and server receives request-parameter, for example locale=en.

Code for generating site-page may contain something like this:

```
String path = ...;  //--- Path to folder with *.properties files

if (locale.equals("en")) path += "I18n_en.properties";
else path += "I18n_es.properties";

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
try {
    resourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(fis);
} finally {
    fis.close();
}
```

Your Category object must have 'name' property. This 'name' must contain needed key from *.propeties. In our case - name="category.dinners".

You get Category object from Database. Now you need put text in needed locale:

```
String htmlForResponse = ...;  //--- Your HTML-page

htmlForResponse += "<div>" + resourceBundle.getString(category.getName()) + "</div>";
```

This is not the best solution. This only demonstrates you some possible steps. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You should use mechanism called internationalization (i18n).
Here you can find an example how to do it in Spring:
http://simplespringtutorial.com/i18n.html

The common approach is to store translation in properties files with language suffix like `messages_fr.properties` and so on, not in a database.

Comment: And if for example: one english user (admin) can add a category "Drinks" but his coworker is spanish, and he want to read "Bebidas". In the Add Category form can ask the new category name in three or four languages, but are saved in .properties file?

Comment: You can use some button on the site to select needed language. After button-click your pages must be reloaded (if you don't use Ajax), and while server counstructs pages new localized messages will be read from *.properties files. You must link to 'keys' (you define them in *.properties files by key=value) in your site-pages.